# Styled-components props being passed but not adapting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
const Shape = styled.div`
background-color: ${props => props.bgColor || 'red'};
`

function shape(props) {
    console.log(props.bgColor || 'red')

    return (
        <Shape>    
        </Shape>
    )    
}
```

I'm passing the following props in via spread operator.

```
let square2x2 = { bgColor: "blue"}

<Shape {...square2x2}></Shape>
```

the console.log shows the props.bgColor exists and returns blue.  However the element is still red. I also confirmed the props exist through React dev tools.  Where am I messing up?

Edit: Solution, pass the props into Shape with `<Shape {...props}/>`

Comment: You pass props into `shape`, but that doesn't pass the props into `Shape` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props must be passed to Shape too:

```
function shape(props) {    
    return (
        <Shape bgColor={props.bgColor} />
    )    
}
```

You need to understand, that when you are passing it to `shape` you are still not inside the styled div object, the styled div object that instantiates the component is `Shape` inside `shape`, props inside `shape` are outside of the scope of `Shape`, so you must pass them to `Shape` to.

Comment: Thank you! That does fix it and your explanation makes sense.  If I wanted to pass all of the props at once what would I need to write?  `<Shape props={props} />` would be wrong I assume.  Would I need to adjust the formulas in `styled.div` to something like `background-color: ${attributes => attributes.bgColor || 'red'};` while simultaneously passing in props by `<Shape attributes={...props}/>`?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: I just have to write `<Shape {...props}/>` Whoops.  Thanks again.  I voted you up by the way but I have less than 15 rep so it won't update the public score.  Don't know why someone downvoted you.